# Moving Circles with Polyline's points concurrently in SVG

Tags: svg, svg-animate, jquery-svg

I wish to make the circles move along the with polyline's points while the polyline is animating.

This is my progress so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/xgr6q4cy/

Here is my codes:

```
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 415 415" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <polyline 
            id="poly1"
            fill="blue" 
            stroke="red" 
            stroke-linecap="round"
            points="97,122 34,85 90,35 198,40 34,85"
            >
            <animate 
                id="one"
                attributeName="points"
                dur="5s" 
                begin="0s;two.end"
            to="97,82 34,85 90,55 198,40 34,85"
            fill="freeze"
            />
            <animate 
                id="two"
                attributeName="points" 
                dur="5s" 
                begin="one.end"
            to="97,122 34,85 90,35 198,40 34,85"
            fill="freeze"
            />


        </polyline>

        <circle cx="34" cy="85" r="3" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="90" cy="35" r="3" fill="red"></circle>
        
        <circle cx="198" cy="40" r="3" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="97" cy="122" r="3" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Screenshots of my progress:

[image]
[image]

I want to make sure the circles follow the polyline while the polyline is animating by using SVG SMIL

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to animate the circles you will need to animate the `cy` attribute using the same `begin` and `dur` values as the animation of the polyline.

Please observe that for the animation I'm using a `values` attribute instead of the `to` & `from` attributes. The values are separated with semicolons (;). The first and the last values are the same.

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 415 415" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline id="poly1" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-linecap="round" points="97,122 34,85 90,35 198,40 34,85">
    <animate attributeName="points" 
             dur="5s" 
             begin="0s" 
             repeatCount="indefinite" 
             values="97,82 34,85 90,55 198,40 34,85;
                     97,122 34,85 90,35 198,40 34,85;
                     97,82 34,85 90,55 198,40 34,85" />
  </polyline>

  <circle cx="34" cy="85" r="3" fill="red"></circle>
  <circle cx="198" cy="40" r="3" fill="red"></circle>
  <circle cx="90" cy="35" r="3" fill="red">
    <animate attributeName="cy" 
             dur="5s" 
             begin="0s" 
             repeatCount="indefinite" 
             values="55;35;55" />
  </circle>
  <circle cx="97" cy="122" r="3" fill="red">
    <animate attributeName="cy" 
             dur="5s" 
             begin="0s" 
             repeatCount="indefinite" 
             values="82;122;82" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker), a graphic that is drawn at polyline points (no matter how they move).

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 415 415" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <!--define a marker - the red circle-->
    <marker id="circle" refX="3" refY="3" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" viewport="0 0 6 6">
        <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="3" fill="red"></circle>
    </marker>

    <!--here the marker-* attributes put the circle marker to every point-->
    <!--marker-end isn't actually needed in your case-->
    <!--because the end-point is the same as the second one-->
    <polyline 
        marker-start="url(#circle)"
        marker-mid="url(#circle)"
        marker-end="url(#circle)"
        
        id="poly1"
        fill="blue" 
        stroke="red" 
        stroke-linecap="round"
        points="97,122 34,85 90,35 198,40 34,85"
        >
        <animate 
            id="one"
            attributeName="points"
            dur="5s" 
            begin="0s;two.end"
        to="97,82 34,85 90,55 198,40 34,85"
        fill="freeze"
        />
        <animate 
            id="two"
            attributeName="points" 
            dur="5s" 
            begin="one.end"
        to="97,122 34,85 90,35 198,40 34,85"
        fill="freeze"
        />

    <!--no more circles are needed-->

    </polyline>


</svg>
```